# Troubleshooting RMAN-03009: failure of delete command on d1 channel

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

I don't have many experience about RMAN backup. I'm running backup daily level 1 incremental backup and weekly Level 0 incremental. Backup files will kept at 2 difference locations (each  location one copy of backup files).
My backup command:

```
run {
allocate channel d1 device type disk format '/nfs_rman_bk/mydb_bk/incr_%d_set%s_piece%p_copy%c_%T_%U','/nfs_rman_bk2/mydb_bk/incr_%d_set%s_piece%p_copy%c_%T_%U';
backup incremental level=1 database plus archivelog ;
backup CURRENT CONTROLFILE FORMAT '/nfs_rman_bk/mydb_bk/ctrl_%d_set%s_piece%p_copy%c_%T_%U','/nfs_rman_bk2/mydb_bk/ctrl_%d_set%s_piece%p_copy%c_%T_%U';
report obsolete;
delete noprompt obsolete;
release channel d1;
}
```

Everything had run smoothly until this `'/nfs_rman_bk2/mydb_bk'` location was broken, can not read and write to. Then I only run backup to remaining location `'/nfs_rman_bk/mydb_bk'`. The RMAN backup command running normally but it failed at this part:

```
delete noprompt obsolete;
```

and backup job raised one error message at the end.

`man-03009: failure of delete command on d1 channel`

If I can not delete obsoleted backup files, the backup location just keep growing until full.

How can I address this problem?

Comment: Hi, man-03009 is a very generic error message which does not indicate anything, please provide the full error sequence.

Comment: Did you try removing the broken path from the `d1` channel definition?

Answer (score 0):

You may do

`list backup;`

and try to set those backupsets on the bad NFS to status unavailable

`change backupset <no> unavailable;`

if the device gets accessible again you can set those backupsets available again - or delete them.